# How to display three grid in netzke

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, extjs, netzke

How to display three grid in netzke.

The tables I want display are,

Boss => Clerk => Task

has_many relation between Boss and Clerk and also,
has_many relation between Clerk and Task.

Please help me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the following tutorial as a starting point: https://github.com/netzke/netzke/wiki/Building-a-composite-component